# Display all categories and all subcategories

Tags: magento2

I have following code to show all categories and all subcategories that is included in menu which works fine.

```
 namespace Categories\Display\Block\Adminhtml\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Container
{



    protected $_categoryHelper;
     protected $categoryFlatConfig;
     protected $topMenu;
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category $categoryHelper
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category $categoryHelper,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Category\Flat\State $categoryFlatState,
        \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu $topMenu
    ) {
        $this->_categoryHelper = $categoryHelper;
        $this->categoryFlatConfig = $categoryFlatState;
        $this->topMenu = $topMenu;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    /**
     * Return categories helper
     */   
    public function getCategoryHelper()
    {
        return $this->_categoryHelper;
    }
    /**
     * Return top menu html
     * getHtml($outermostClass = '', $childrenWrapClass = '', $limit = 0)
     * example getHtml('level-top', 'submenu', 0)
     */   
    public function getHtml()
    {
        return $this->topMenu->getHtml();
    }
    /**
     * Retrieve current store categories
     *
     * @param bool|string $sorted
     * @param bool $asCollection
     * @param bool $toLoad
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node\Collection|\Magento\Catalog\Model\Resource\Category\Collection|array
     */    
   public function getStoreCategories($sorted = false, $asCollection = false, $toLoad = true)
    {
        return $this->_categoryHelper->getStoreCategories($sorted , $asCollection, $toLoad);
    }
    /**
     * Retrieve child store categories
     *
     */ 
    public function getChildCategories($category)
    {
           if ($this->categoryFlatConfig->isFlatEnabled() && $category->getUseFlatResource()) {
                $subcategories = (array)$category->getChildrenNodes();
            } else {
                $subcategories = $category->getChildren();
            }
            return $subcategories;
    }



}
```

Now I need all categories and subcategories including not enabled for menu.

Could you please help?

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the categories using category collection.

```
<?php

private $categoryCollection;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category $categoryCollection
) {
    ...
    $this->categoryCollection = $categoryCollection;
}

$all_categories = $this->categoryCollection->getCollection();
echo "<pre>";
print_r($all_categories->getData());
```

Comment: Hello Thanks for the reply. I know that we can get it by category collection. But I need all parent categories and associated subcategories